# How to disable 'routed mode' for modules?

Tags: php, fuelphp, fuelphp-routing

On the FuelPHP documentation located here http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/modules.html it states:

"When you use modules in routed mode,..."

This implies there's a non-routed mode for modules.

Basically i don't want fuel to route to modules automatically, i have implemented a basic 'bootstrapping' system for modules, and i explicitly define the routes for my modules in the bootstrap files.

This works but when i enter the default route / url for the module like:  /myrealmodule/controllername/method it still loads my module, my custom route defined in my bootstrapping files also works, but i want to stop FuelPHP from automatically routing to my modules, how do i disable this behaviour?

I have read over the documentation several times and i am pretty sure i've not missed it, it's just not mentioned on there apart from in the link supplied above.

Answer (score 0):

No, modules are always routed automatically. You can't disable it.